# Swift 3: Expression type [UIImage] is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, uiimage

I try to create new array of UIImage objects:

```
var images = [UIImage](repeating: nil, count: 10)
for i in 0..<10
    {
        images[i] = ...
    }
```

But I got this error (at first row):
**Expression type [UIImage] is ambiguous without more context**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to declare an array with `UIImage` objects and then instantiating with nil. Try

```
var images = [UIImage?](repeating: nil, count: 10)
```

and then handle images being nil when you access them.

If you already know how you are going to populate images, you can use the map function for arrays like so:

```
var images = (0..<10).map { (i) -> UIImage in
    return UIImage() // however you are trying to get the UIImage
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus That's okay too! I just gave the `optional` suggestion to be more efficient. You don't want to allocate objects that are going to be discarded right away.

Comment: I think the correct approach would be just create an empty array `var images = [UIImage]()` and then append the new images to it inside his loop or as you suggested using map or forEach `(0..<10).forEach { images.append(UIImage(named:"image\($0)") ?? UIImage()) }`